# Fetch Unfollower Instagram api swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, instagram

Can i fetch details of unfollower of Instagram user using instagram api?

If it's possible then how can i do it????

I used relationship endpoint to do it

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/relationship?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

let newJson1 = JSON(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/\(self.id)/relationship?access_token=\(self.accessToken)")!)!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil)

            print(newJson1)
```

but none of the results found....

Do you have some advices? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@John Instagram limits the api access. For that you have to approve your app permission from the sandbox. Once the Instagram approves your permission, then you can access of the relevant data. Approving permission can be done by submitting your app to Instagram.

Comment: What is sand box? @vimaldiwani

Comment: Sorry @John its permission tab. Go to manage clients in developer account then click edit client tab. Their you will find permission tab. Select the permission which your app want and submit the app for approval.

Comment: Thanks @vimaldiwani I will try your suggestion.